# How to avoid conditions in left join and optimize query?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

I'm having a little problem at work, the ORM is generating a very strange query and I need to optimize its result a little. I wrote a more readable version of the query and the result is similar, but the execution time is still the same.

[Original Query](https://pastebin.com/SzEqL1Ws)
[Explain Verbose](https://explain.depesz.com/s/17Mi)

This is the current formatted query, it returns the correct value but takes about 13 seconds to execute.

```
select count(*)
from reservation as r
         JOIN companyclient as cc ON r.companyclientid = cc.companyclientid
         JOIN reservationitem as ri ON r.reservationid = ri.reservationid
         LEFT JOIN billingaccount as bi
                   ON (r.reservationid = bi.reservationid AND cc.companyclientid = bi.companyclientid AND
                       bi.propertyid = '84'
                       AND NOT bi.isdeleted
                       AND bi.groupkey = bi.billingaccountid
                       AND bi.billingaccounttypeid = '3'
                       AND bi.reservationid IS NOT NULL
                       AND bi.statusid = '1')
WHERE r.propertyid = '84'
  AND NOT r.isdeleted
  AND r.companyclientid is not null
  AND ri.tenantid = '025aa64f-67fb-4c23-b975-2b0fc3f5d65a'
  AND NOT ri.isdeleted
  AND ri.reservationitemstatusid NOT IN (6, 3, 7, 8);
```

[Explain Verbose](https://explain.depesz.com/s/5dKT#html)

This is the version I wrote in an attempt to optimize (from 13 seconds to 5), avoiding the conditions inside the left join, but the result is different from the original query. The first query returns 29490 and the second query returns 29397.

```
select count(*)
from reservation as r
         JOIN companyclient as cc ON r.companyclientid = cc.companyclientid
         JOIN reservationitem as ri ON r.reservationid = ri.reservationid
         LEFT JOIN billingaccount as bi
                   ON (r.reservationid = bi.reservationid AND cc.companyclientid = bi.companyclientid)
WHERE r.propertyid = '84'
  AND NOT r.isdeleted
  AND r.companyclientid is not null
  AND ri.tenantid = '025aa64f-67fb-4c23-b975-2b0fc3f5d65a'
  AND NOT ri.isdeleted
  AND ri.reservationitemstatusid NOT IN (6, 3, 7, 8)
  AND (bi is null or bi.propertyid = '84'
  AND NOT bi.isdeleted
  AND bi.groupkey = bi.billingaccountid
  AND bi.billingaccounttypeid = '3'
  AND bi.reservationid IS NOT NULL
  AND bi.statusid = '1')
```

[Explain Verbose](https://explain.depesz.com/s/CLIr)

My question is, how can I optimize the first query, I've tried some methods but I haven't had much success. I understand that the count is linear and its time is based on the size of the query return, but I imagine it's too slow for a 30K rows query.

In this specific case, I need the total of items to calculate the number of pages in the limit offset pagination.

Thanks in advance to everyone who had the patience to read, I accept any help.

Size of tables used in the example:

- reservation: 288549 rows
- companyclient: 50614 rows
- reservationitem: 387820 rows
- billingaccount: 772521 rows

Comment: Occasionally, I've sped things up by grouping the id's in an inner query and then doing the rest of the where clauses etc. in the 'outer query' so it is the same overall query.  If indexed properly, this can dramatically improve speed, but it doesn't always work.

Comment: I suggest you add the `CREATE TABLE` statements for all 3 tables, including indexes - or the output of `\d reservation` from psql (again for all 3 tables).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some thoughts about the query. If we had the tables structure and indexes, it would be more helpful (and the advice maybe different):

- The 2nd query is not equivalent to the 1st so it's not unusual that you get different results. So let's stick to the first query:

  ```
    select count(*)
    from reservation as r
             JOIN companyclient as cc ON r.companyclientid = cc.companyclientid
             JOIN reservationitem as ri ON r.reservationid = ri.reservationid
             LEFT JOIN billingaccount as bi
                       ON (r.reservationid = bi.reservationid
                           AND cc.companyclientid = bi.companyclientid
                           AND bi.propertyid = '84'
                           AND NOT bi.isdeleted
                           AND bi.groupkey = bi.billingaccountid
                           AND bi.billingaccounttypeid = '3'
                           AND bi.reservationid IS NOT NULL
                           AND bi.statusid = '1')
    WHERE r.propertyid = '84'
      AND NOT r.isdeleted
      AND r.companyclientid is not null
      AND ri.tenantid = '025aa64f-67fb-4c23-b975-2b0fc3f5d65a'
      AND NOT ri.isdeleted
      AND ri.reservationitemstatusid NOT IN (6, 3, 7, 8);
  ```
- The conditions `r.companyclientid is not null` and `bi.reservationid IS NOT NULL` are redundant since these columns already participate in joining conditions and any NULL value will not pass the joining conditions. So these two can be safely removed (but still check that you get the same results).
- The `cc.companyclientid = bi.companyclientid` condition (inside the subquery) can be replaced with `r.companyclientid = bi.companyclientid` since you have the equality condition in the outer query: `r.companyclientid = cc.companyclientid`. This leaves no `cc` column in the subquery and all the subquery's conditions involve only 2 tables, `bi` and `r` and it might help Postgres' planner to get a more simple plan (especially if there are suitable indexes on `billingaccount` and `reservation`.
- If **and only if** the `reservation. companyclientid` is not nullable **and** there is a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint that `REFERENCES companyclient (companyclientid)`, then we can completely remove the `JOIN companyclient as cc ON r.companyclientid = cc.companyclientid` since for any row in `reservation`, the foreign guarantees that there is a single row in `companyclient` and the count would not be affected.
- use `count(1)` instead of `count(*)`. This is just a minor improvement in some versions.

If all the above are applied, the query would become
*(and don't forget to compare results with the original correct query after every modification!)*:

```
    select count(1)
    from reservation as r
             JOIN reservationitem as ri ON r.reservationid = ri.reservationid
             LEFT JOIN billingaccount as bi
                       ON (r.reservationid = bi.reservationid
                           AND r.companyclientid = bi.companyclientid
                           AND bi.propertyid = '84'
                           AND NOT bi.isdeleted
                           AND bi.groupkey = bi.billingaccountid
                           AND bi.billingaccounttypeid = '3'
                           AND bi.statusid = '1')
    WHERE r.propertyid = '84'
      AND NOT r.isdeleted
      AND ri.tenantid = '025aa64f-67fb-4c23-b975-2b0fc3f5d65a'
      AND NOT ri.isdeleted
      AND ri.reservationitemstatusid NOT IN (6, 3, 7, 8);
```

Now let's suggest some indexes, specifically for this query and one for each table:

```
CREATE INDEX suggested_index_a ON
reservation
    (propertyid, reservationid, companyclientid)
WHERE (NOT isdeleted) ;

CREATE INDEX suggested_index_b ON
reservationitem
    (tenantid, reservationid) 
INCLUDE (reservationitemstatusid)
WHERE (NOT isdeleted) ;

CREATE INDEX suggested_index_c ON
billingaccount
    (propertyid, billingaccounttypeid, statusid,
     reservationid, companyclientid)
WHERE (groupkey = billingaccountid 
       AND NOT isdeleted) ;
```

Please try with the above indexes added. Have in mind that any index consumes disk space (and memory space when used) so it is a trade off.

Comment: Thanks for your amazing answer. The result was slightly larger than expected, it returned 29968 rows. I will check all the points you mentioned.

Comment: The result returned different because the join with companyclient is necessary, but your query is around 60% faster, now I will check the indexes.

Comment: so there is no FK :(

Comment: Using the indices, the query runs in 1.1 seconds! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

While that surely is a oddly written query, using the plan we can see there is a missing index on billingaccount, without having to understand what the design of the overall query is.

You shouldn't need to scan and reject 7649 rows just to return 84, so some of the columns in the filter should be part of the index.  We don't know how selective each part of the filter is, but based on the column names and constants, I am guessing you need a multicolumn index over both companyclientid and propertyid.  (And should probably have billingaccounttypeid and statusid in it as well, it shouldn't hurt much and might help)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the reply!
I'll have a look if any more indexes can be added.